# Using TABLES and INCLUDES

Tags: php, html-table, include

I'm trying to to a simple page organized with various php includes inside tables.

My problem is: when I put a `<?php include('header.php');?>` in `<td>`of the tables it creates a space between them.

Here is the test page that I'm trying to do: http://www.dmaispublicidade.pt/_dmaisprojecto

Is an index.php with a table calling others .php files (that even have tables and other includes)?

This white spaces between images it is supposed to not be there!

Can anybody help?

Example of index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>d+ projecto</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php include('header.php'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php include('corpo.php'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php include('footer.php'); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example of header.php:

```
<table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="imagens/provisorio/header.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example of the css (that is called inside the head of index.php):

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

When we saw the source code in the test page, we can saw that is inserting (I don't know how) a TBODY in the document; I don't know why. There is something to remove the TBODY by CSS?

Comment: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: Are there spaces at the beginning or end of header.php? For example, after ?> inside header.php

Comment: It looks like a lot has to do with your comments you have put in.  You may have white space around it.  You should also look into using css instead of tables.

Comment: please, remove code from comments and update your question. Nobody likes to read code this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I viewed your test site and downloaded the source, there are invisible characters inserted after the `<td>` and before the contents of your included file. I copied into Notepad++ and had to change to ANSI encoding to even see it. I would turn on view all characters in whatever editor you are using and see if you can find the visible characters to remove.

#### Update:

Using a hex editor I've found that your files are encoded with UTF-8 with BOM. This [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character is causing the display issue. Googling found that W3C has an [article](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en.php) covering this and how to remove the BOM character from your files.

Additional Info:

- [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

Tools used to debug:

- [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: yes i saw it too :( but that code is not in my files. ... do u know how to fix that? thks.

Comment: Is inserting a TBODY in the documento :S i dont know why. There is someting to remove the TBODY by CSS?

Comment: THIS UR POST UPDATE WORKS!!! - Thank u!! The problem was the BOM ... all php files was with UTF-8 BOM (except index.php) .... Now is all without.it. Thanks a lot!! Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the:

```
<!----------------------  MENU  ---------------------->
```

which is adding an extra (non) element to the document.

Comment: i had removed all comments of the documents. still with spaces. :(